# Zoom camera in Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, zooming

I'm using this lib for displaying a camera (https://pub.dev/packages/camera), however, I'd like to set a predefined zoom value for the camera before it starts, but I'm not able to identify where I can set it using this lib.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Here's the code I got so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    buscarCameras();
  }

  Future<void> buscarCameras() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });


}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(controller == null || controller.value == null)
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );

    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(controller));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1304

Answer (score 3):

Flutter has added zoom support as of [Camera version 0.6.2](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/changelog). You can use `cameraController.setZoomLevel(4.0);` in your code to adjust the zoom level.

There are also other helpful functions, such as `cameraControl.getMaxZoomLevel();` to find the limits for the zoom level.

There isn't any documentation for this feature at time of writing, as it is very recent, but you can look through the [code for the camera controller](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/camera/lib/src/camera_controller.dart) to see the available methods.

Answer (score 3):

Create your zoom variable in state class:

```
class _ShowCameraState extends State<ShowCamera> {
  CameraController _cameraController;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  double zoom = 0.0;
   }
```

And then in a widget, create slider:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _initializeControllerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return CameraPreview(_cameraController);
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Slider(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          value: zoom,
          onChanged: (value) {
            print(value);
// as slider values are in decimals, we multiply it by 10 because camera
//take values above 1.0 and below 8.0
//e.g:
//value=0.19 //according to slider
//value=value*10=> 0.19*10
//Now the updated value is:
//value=1.9

            value = value * 10;
            if (value <= 8.0 && value >= 1.0) {
//Here we set the zoom level when we move slider pointer
              _cameraController.setZoomLevel(value);
            }
//and to set slider pointer position visually, we divided the value by 10 
//to give slider its original value.
            setState(() => zoom = value / 10);
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to do it now: Wrap your CameraPreview widget inside a GestureDetector and add the below code block inside it (you must initialize your CameraController before this).

```
onScaleUpdate: (details) async {
          var maxZoomLevel = await camController.getMaxZoomLevel();
          // just calling it dragIntensity for now, you can call it whatever you like.
          var dragIntensity = details.scale;
          if (dragIntensity < 1) {
            // 1 is the minimum zoom level required by the camController's method, hence setting 1 if the user zooms out (less than one is given to details when you zoom-out/pinch-in).
            camController.setZoomLevel(1);
          } else if (dragIntensity > 1 && dragIntensity < maxZoomLevel) {
            // self-explanatory, that if the maxZoomLevel exceeds, you will get an error (greater than one is given to details when you zoom-in/pinch-out).
            camController.setZoomLevel(dragIntensity);
          } else {
            // if it does exceed, you can provide the maxZoomLevel instead of dragIntensity (this block is executed whenever you zoom-in/pinch-out more than the max zoom level).
            camController.setZoomLevel(maxZoomLevel);
          }
        },
```

Very simple logic and gets the job done right away, but you can optimize it further for better user experience if you need.